# How to Read selected values from a list of checkboxes loaded in JQM via ajax call bound using knockoutjs?

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am developing a mobile application using JQuery Mobile and KnockoutJS. was able to successfully load a list of checkboxes from an AJAX Call. the list of checkboxes have been bound using knockout js foreach binding. However I could not figureout a way to get the selected checkbox values from the lsit. Any ideas would be highly appreciable.

Here is my HTML

```
 <p>
    Select Items(s):
    <div id="itemList">
    <ul id="itemList" data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" >
        <fieldset id="myList" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="foreach : Items">
            <li id="chkRoles" data-role="fieldcontain" data-filter="true">
               <input data-theme="c" type="checkbox" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': Id, name: 'checkbox-' + Id, id: 'checkbox-' + Id  }" />
                <label data-theme="c" data-bind="text: ItemName, attr: { for: 'checkbox-' + Id }"></label>
            </li>
     </fieldset>
     </ul>
    </div>
</p>
```

My ViewModel JS

```
    ItemViewModel = function(){
var self = this;
self.Items = ko.observableArray([])
}

var viewModel = new ItemViewModel();

//doing an AJAX call to load ObservableArray
viewModel.Items(data);
$("#itemList").listview("refresh").find('input').checkboxradio();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have another observableArray to hold the checked values only. 
Then, if you give your checkboxes a 'value' attribute, and use the 'checked' binding on them, specifying the observableArray, the array should automatically be updated only with the values of the checked inputs. (This is all [explained here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html))

I put your code into a jsfiddle and made those changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/ektUp/